# ERROR in Illegal state when using two modules in one App

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I have a login page where I'am using guard feature. So, Once the user enters the correct data (username and pass), he will be redirected to the profile page `/profile/profile.component.ts`.

Now I would like to use an extra module for the protected pages/components `/profile/profile.component.ts` and redirect to it from router module, when login succeed. Therefore I did, first of all, generate a new/second module called: `dashboard.module.ts` where I do have an app component `app.component`. The structure looks as following:

```
/src
  /app
     app.module.ts
     app.component.ts
     router.ts
     /dashboard
        /app
           app.component.ts
        dashboard.module.ts
```

dashborad.component.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/dashboard/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule 
    ],
    exports: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

app.component.ts under /dashboard:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
@NgModule({
    exports:[]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I can start the app with `ng serve` without any errors, but when I run AOT (Ahead-of-Time Compilation), then I get the following error:

`ERROR in Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive AppComponent in /Users/user/Dev/dashboard-app/src/app/dashboard/app/app.component.ts.`

When I add export `AppComponent` in app.component.ts:

```
    ...
    @NgModule({
        exports:[AppComponent]
    })
    ...
```

I face this error:

```
ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/user/Dev/dashboard-app/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Any idea to fix this please? or am I building totally a wrong structure and/or wrong concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. I did change the structure of the Not-Public components... now the dashboard folder contains a module: `dashboard.module.ts` and the other subfolders which are accessible after user-login. Also I did change and fix the declarations and exports in `dashboard.module.ts`

Structure:

```
src/
   app/
      dashboard/
          dashboard.component.ts
          dashboard.component.html
          dashboard.component.css
          dashboard.module.ts
          profile/
             profile.component.ts
             profile.component.html
             profile.component.css
          add/
            add.component.ts
            add.component.html
            add.component.css
          ....
      signup/
      howto/
main.ts
```

dashboard.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { AddComponent } from './add/add.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { MaterialModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdAutocompleteModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdInputModule,
    MdRadioModule, MdSelectModule, MdSliderModule, MdSlideToggleModule, MdMenuModule, MdSidenavModule, MdToolbarModule,
    MdListModule, MdGridListModule, MdCardModule, MdTabsModule, MdButtonModule, MdButtonToggleModule, MdChipsModule, 
    MdIconModule, MdProgressSpinnerModule, MdProgressBarModule, MdDialogModule, MdTooltipModule, MdSnackBarModule
} from '@angular/material';

const dashBoardRoutes: Routes = [
    { path:'', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch:'full' },
    { path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
        { path:'add', component: AddComponent},
        { path:'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
    ]},

];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProfileComponent, DashboardComponent, AddComponent
    ],

    imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        MdDatepickerModule, MdInputModule, 
        RouterModule.forChild( dashBoardRoutes )
    ],

    providers:[],

    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
    exports:[ProfileComponent, AddComponent],
    bootstrap: [
        DashboardComponent
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```